# Optionally passing command line arguments?

Tags: perl

I need to optionally accept command line argument from my user who's executing my script. (I prefer not to use `GetOptions()`).

I have two variables,

```
my ($port_name, $report);
$port_name = $ARGV[0];
$report = $ARGV[1];

if (defined $port_name){    
    ....
}
if (defined $report){   
    ....
}
```

If `$report` flag is not given as a command line argument then I do not wish to run the second if-block. How can this be done without perl giving me an error?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Well, you may not prefer it, but you should still use [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).

Answer (score -1):

Your code should work as expected.....

```
hi[root@matthewharris cpanel]# perl blah.pl 1
hi[root@matthewharris cpanel]# perl blah.pl 1 2
hino[root@matthewharris cpanel]# 

[root@matthewharris cpanel]# cat blah.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my ( $port, $report ) = @ARGV;

if ( $port ) {
    print 'hi';
}
if ( $report ) {
    print 'no';
}
```

Comment: He didn't ask about validation :P

Comment: That's not validation, as much as testing the truthiness vs. the existence. `defined` is good for that.